# How to disable DVC git hooks

Tags: git, githooks, dvc

DVC has Git hooks which are installed with `dvc install`. The hooks were working fine but after an error with `dvc push` and the DVC remote, I cannot `git push` because before `git push` gets executed, `dvc push` runs and generates an error. Which means I can't push.

How can I disable DVC Git hooks so that I won't face the issue anymore?

Comment: It's in the command reference :) https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/install#disable-git-hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All installed git hooks will be inside `.git/hooks`. Your problem is with the `pre-push` hook:

```
$ ls .git/hooks
applypatch-msg.sample      post-checkout          pre-commit               pre-push               pre-push.sample     prepare-commit-msg.sample
commit-msg.sample          post-update.sample     pre-commit.sample        pre-rebase.sample   update.sample
fsmonitor-watchman.sample  pre-applypatch.sample  pre-merge-commit.sample  pre-receive.sample
```

Remove that and you will be fine:

```
$ rm -rf .git/hooks/pre-push
```

Note that other hooks like `dvc checkout` for `git checkout` still work. If you want to disable all hooks, not just dvc-installed, you can run:

```
$ rm -rf .git/hooks/*
```

Comment: you don't need `-r` or `-f` for normal files